# follow a person using openni_tracker

Tags: ros, openi-tracker, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I have openni_tracker working and I would try to make my pioneer follow the detected user.
My idea was to use the tf data give by openni_tracker but I don't how to use them to make the robot moving.
Do you guys have any idea?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248463/follow-a-person-using-openni_tracker/) by [PinoPatatino](https://answers.ros.org/users/28575/pinopatatino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can get the coordinates(relative to the sensor) of the detected user by utilizing the transform from openni_depth_frame to skeleton point like head_1, left_hand_1 and so on. Depending on the coordinates, you can get the distance from the user to the robot through the X coordinate and whether the robot is on the left or the right of the user through the Y coordinate. Then you can make the robot move right or left or faster according to the above info.

---

Originally posted by [FrankYou](https://answers.ros.org/users/28058/frankyou/) with karma: 46 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1